# different time in google calendar when adding events from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-sheets

time changes when added to google calender by google appscript and spreedsheet:
code for app script (only time portion):

```
function setUpCalendar_(values, range) {
var cal = CalendarApp.createCalendar('Conference Calendar');

Browser.msgBox('Calender time zone: ' + cal.getTimeZone()); 
//to check timezone for debugging.

for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
var session = values[i];
var title = session[0];
var start = joinDateAndTime_(session[1], session[2]);
var end = joinDateAndTime_(session[1], session[3]);
var options = {location: session[4], sendInvites: true};
var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, options)
                .setGuestsCanSeeGuests(false);
//session[5] = event.getId();
   ///====:::: test :::: replacingsession[5] with values[i][5]
   }

range.setValues(values);

// Store the ID for the Calendar, which is needed to retrieve events by ID.
ScriptProperties.setProperty('calId', cal.getId());
}

function joinDateAndTime_(date, time) {
  date = new Date(date);
  date.setHours(time.getHours());
  date.setMinutes(time.getMinutes());
  Browser.msgBox(date); // to check time for debuging.
  return date;
  }
```

Link to spreadsheet with script:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AorrYgKfVJpQdEdBY2lYdEpIUUc0TlRRUkNlNmRPTWc&usp=sharing

steps taken so far:
1. changed timezone of spreadsheet to locale.
2. changed timezone of calender to locale.

result:
different time in spreadsheet and calender.

issue:
must be same time in spreadsheet and calender.

references:

[calendarApp createEvent added event on wrong day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410846/calendarapp-createevent-added-event-on-wrong-day)

[How to use timeZone of calendar to set timeZone for date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645343/how-to-use-timezone-of-calendar-to-set-timezone-for-date-object)

Comment: What difference do you notice? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: both minutes and hours. see spreadsheet provided in link. @Sergeinsas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had that kind of issue when using your method to join date and time from spreadsheet to JavaScript date object (some random values added to hours and/or minutes) so I found another approach that works more reliably...(while - I admit - less academic...)

I tested in a copy of your spreadsheet and when I setiup a conference the events are created as they should (in Calcutta Time, which is not perfect for me but I "moved" temporarily to check the results ;-)

here is the code, just copy and paste in your script to replace your function.

```
function joinDateAndTime_(date, time){
  var hrs = Number(Utilities.formatDate(time,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'HH'));
  var min = Number(Utilities.formatDate(time,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'mm'));
  var sec = Number(Utilities.formatDate(time,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'ss'));
  Logger.log('date = '+Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone() ,'dd-MMM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss'));
  Logger.log('time = '+hrs+':'+min+':'+sec);
  var dateAndTime = new Date(date).setHours(hrs,min,sec,0);
  Logger.log('full date object = '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateAndTime), Session.getScriptTimeZone() ,'dd-MMM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss'))
  return new Date(dateAndTime);
}
```

Don't forget to check the timezones of the Sheet and script... (since you mentioned you tried different setups) They must of course match your area and calendars.

Comment: Thanks, Honestly I have no idea why the "normal" way does not work... I didn't find any mention of it on the issue tracker... maybe one should post it there.