# Getting current user timezone

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using `Session.getTimeZone()` to get the current user's timezone. I just noticed it has been [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getTimeZone()), and I can't see anything that replicates this functionality. My users are located all over the US and dates/times should be formatted accordingly. How can I get the current user's timezone and not that of the script/owner?

The project in question is a standalone script.

Comment: What is the end result of the users timezone?  Store in Db or post to google calendar?

Comment: @LennyZ71 In this project I use it almost exclusively in Utilities.formatDate()

Answer (score 6):

Greg, normal javascript seems to be working as intended this might be new in gas.  The second example of code's function is returning the correct timezone offset for me. 
I'm currently using the Session.getTimeZone() in a gasOffsetScript.
Question here might be a good read for the future.
[Using Calendar Timezone to set event Timezone, not the users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645343/how-to-use-timezone-of-calendar-to-set-timezone-for-date-object)

This next code will get the users timezone based off their default Calendar Setting, if the script is running as the user.

```
function getUserTimeZone() {
  var userTimeZone = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getTimeZone();
  Logger.log(userTimeZone)
}
```

Or you could modify the following using normal javascript.

Code that is returning users timezone 
[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

```
function userTimeZone() {
  function pad(number, length){
    var str = "" + number
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = '0'+str
    }
    return str
}

var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
offset = ((offset<0? '+':'-')+ // Note the reversed sign!
          pad(parseInt(Math.abs(offset/60)), 2)+
          pad(Math.abs(offset%60), 2))
  Logger.log(offset)
}
```

Good luck brother, timezones are thorns.

Answer (score 3):

Use the spreadsheet's time zone: `getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`

If you use a standalone script, your only hope is to create a temporary spreadsheet on the user's drive (you would need to publish it to run as the user) and then see the default time-zone the spreadsheet has.

More Info: [Google Developers - Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetTimeZone()%3Cbr%3E)

Comment: This is a standalone script. I edited the post for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

In **Gmail Add-ons** you can get the user timezone and locale in buildAddOn parameters by activating the useLocaleFromApp. [Check the documentation of Accessing User Locale and Timezone](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/access-user-locale)

Step to get the timezone and locale:

1. In manifest add useLocaleFromApp with true `"useLocaleFromApp": true`
2. Add the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"
3. In buildAddOn you will receive the parameter userLocale and userTimezone

Manifest example:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Etc/GMT"
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "TestApp",
    "logoUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxxx/favicon.ico",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
    }],
    "primaryColor": "#fea001",
    "secondaryColor": "#fea001",
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": ["https://mail.google.com/"],
    "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2",
    "useLocaleFromApp": true
  }
}
```

Add-ons example:

```
function buildAddOn(e) 
{
  var cards = [];

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder().setName("Test timeZone");

  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("test"));

  var section = CardService.newCardSection();

  section.addWidget( CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(e.userLocale));
  section.addWidget( CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(e.userTimezone.offSet));
  section.addWidget( CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(e.userTimezone.id));

  card.addSection(section);

  cards.push( card.build());

  return cards;
}
```

> Caution with userTimezone.offSet parameter. The parameter have
>   distinct case that the referenced in the documentation. The parameter
>   is userTimezone.offSet with S uppercase